# how to call different php file on a single webpage?

Tags: php

I have 3 php files and one webpage.

When I click on a navbar link, how can I change from ?php include 'sample1.php'; ? to ?php include 'sample2.php'; ? using the same template. Instead of making multiple templates. Is this possible? - thanks

Example:
On the template the active is ?php include 'sample1.php'; ---- when I click sample2 link on the navbar... the template stays the same but sample2.php will be placed and sample1.php is removed -thanks

Navbar - Home   -   Sample1    Sample2

```
Sample1 is active and it is on the webpage
<?php include 'sample1.php'; ?> 


when I click Sample2 in the navbar, sample one should be replace by 
<?php include 'sample2.php'; ?>
and replace sample1.php on the same webpage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use include or require statement.
Please check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)
Hope this solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have an easy answer. If you place sample1.php inside a , you can change the content with a function in jquery like .click, .onchange, etc. Insede the function you can make ajax to load sample2.php content. To set content in the div, you can use $("#example").html(data);. Data is the response from ajax.